# How to get $(..).html(array) to have the same result as elm.innerHTML = array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this JS/jQuery way on how to display HTML here on this site.

```
<div class="x1"></div>
<div class="x2"></div>

var a = [0, 1];

document.querySelector('.x1').innerHTML = a;

$(".x2").html(a);
```

The code is displaying

`0,1
01`

How do I display arrays in jQuery correctly?

Note: I'm using jQuery 2.2.1

Comment: See [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for how to explicitly turn the array into the expected output. (Although it should also be the same to use: `$(".x2").html("" + a)` in this case.)